# Is there a way to force python to form a linear regression with intercept equal to 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression

I have a dataset including two columns `age` ans `flexibility` variables. The following plot displays the corrolation between the age of people and their body flexibility based on my dataset:

[image]

I am trying to make a cubic model where flexibility depends on the age cubed. So I have done:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df["Age_cubed"] = df["Age"].pow(3)
X = df[["Age_cubed"]]
Y = df["Flexibility"]

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, Y)
r_sq = model.score(X, Y)

model.coef_  # 10.02
model.score(X, Y) # 0.93
```

Now the corresponding plot is:
[image]

This model has an interocept of 0.034:

```
print(model.intercept_) # 0.034
```

Is there a way to force python to form the above linear regression model with intercept equal to 0?

Comment: Is this scikit-learn?

Comment: @ahiijny Yes, `from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way if you set the value of *fit_intercept* to False:

```
model = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
```

Then when you print the intercept:

```
print(model.intercept_)
```

The output is:

```
0.0
```

Answer (score -3):

Unless the line is vertical, there must be an intercept.

Comment: This is not true. The intercept is the value at 0. No intercept just means that the line must go through (0, 0).

Comment: If the line goes through (0,0), the intercept would be 0, which is different from having no intercept.

Comment: ?? A linear model is `wx + b`. No intercept means we just have `wx`. This is the same as `b = 0`.

Comment: Incorrect, the intercept is 0, not none. Similar to how Null != 0, "no intercept" != "intercept of 0".

Comment: This is a meaningless technicality. It is obvious that the question is asking about forcing the intercept to be 0.

Comment: In colloquial speech, people tend to use "0" and "none"/"nothing" interchangeably. It's perhaps slightly sloppy terminology, but I think this is what the OP meant. Perhaps another way to look at it is: A linear model with 0-intercept would have no intercept *term* in the linear model equation.

On an unrelated note, I'm reminded of a joke: "Did you hear about the mathematician who's afraid of negative numbers? They'll stop at nothing to avoid them!" :-)